# Google Tag Manager - custom event - category is undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have started using Google Tag Manager recently and I don't understand why one of my variables remains undefined while everything seems to be set up correctly.

Here is first the code that I use to create my datalayer:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = [{
    'pageCategory': 'test1',
    'Device' : 'test2',
    'Manufacturer': 'test3'
   }];
</script>
```

I have created custom dimensions based on those variables and I can find them in Google Analytics. So far, everything is all right.

I then want to track a click on a button that leads the users to an external link. I use the following code:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  'ShopURL': url,
  'ShopName': shop_name,
  'PriceOffer': price,
  'event': 'ClickPrice'
});
```

I have checked the content of each variable with a console.log and they all display the correct values.

In GTM, I have created datalayer variable for each one of them, I have created a custom event to push them to Google Analytics. I have taken "ShopName" for event_category, "Device" for event_action, "PriceOffer" for event_label.

When I look at the data in Google Analytics I see that event_category is undefined while event_action has the correct value. It looks like the event is fired correctly because I can only see it in GA when I click on the button but somehow some variables are not populated correctly.

You can see it in action here: https://www.mobilemultimedia.be/en/nokia/price-nokia-8.1 (click on one of the "check offer" button to trigger the event)

With GTM preview in the browser I see all the correct values.

Any idea?

**Additional info**
Here is a screenshot of the variable configuration in GTM:
[image]
I'm sorry, it's in French but you can see the variable with the right name.

Comment: When I look at the Google debugger I can see that the undefined value appears already in the request to GA. Since you are using CamelCase for your key names my educated guess is that you created a datalayer variable using the wrong case (variable names are case sensitive).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks! I checked but it looks like the variable name is ok, I have added a screenshot in the initial description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have your trigger set incorrectly.

[image]

I think it might be an element click trigger right now, but you need it to be a "custom event" trigger and you should have "ClickPrice" as the event name you use to trigger.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have changed as suggested but I don't see the events appearing in GA, maybe it's because real time is not really real time. What I see in the GTM preview is that all variables have the right value after the click on the button. Should I set the trigger to fire on all custom events or only when the "ClickPrice" is being fire? I have tried both but I don't see anything in GA.

Comment: I had a look at your site and the event is coming through to GTM correctly.

Comment: yes, it looks like it is working now, thanks for your help!